# UserControl Command Binding in WPF using MVVM pattern

Tags: .net, wpf

I am creating a UserControl  in WPF using MVVM pattern.

I am creating a UserControl with its ViewModel , I need to bind the Commands of a button in UserControl in ViewModel of it.But I am not able to do it ,Please help me if somebody have came across this situation.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please share your code of what have you done so far.

Answer (score 0):

UserControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Project.Views.TestView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels">

  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:TestViewModel/>
  </UserControl.DataContext>

  <Button Command="{binding Path=TestCommand}" Contect="Test"/>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace Project.ViewModels
{ 
  public class TestViewModel
  {
    public ICommand TestCommand{ get;set; }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
      TestCommand = new RelayCommand(TestCommand_OnClick) //your Icommand implementation
    }

    void TestCommand_OnClick(object obj)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Clicked the Test button");
    }
  }
}
```

This will work.
You can add the usercontrol whereever you need it.

Comment: Thanks for the respone Nawed , If I put this user control in ItemsControl , I am not able to bind the data from it , If I put it outside itemscontrol it will work by binding using the ElementName /RelativeSource but its not working for ItemsControl .

Comment: Maybe you should show some code, what is you approach ? Maybe then I can guide you on the correct way.