# WPF MVVM UserControl Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Good evening everyone.  I'm in a sort of a bind with a program I have been writing.  My customers made some changes last week which I thought would be better implemented in MVVM architecture.  In fact I think my entire application would be better in MVVM.  In the beginning the requirements were small so I did not implement MVVM also because I am not well practice with it.

I have been researching stackoverflow, stack exchange, youtube and pretty much everything else I can find to spin up quickly on MVVM.  I have read many posts regarding UserControl binding but I am missing some piece of the puzzle and need to unblock.  So I'm sorry if the content of my post is somewhat duplicated elsewhere.

I have my MainView which contains a Menu Item that calls a command to show a RS422ConfigView.  On this view I have 8 Rs422ConfigControlGroup (UseControls) which contain 8 other controls, all but two are combo boxes.  I am having trouble binding these individual controls such that their child controls may be accessible.  An image of my intended mechanization is below:
[image]

I have added dependency properties to my Rs422DeviceControlGroup.xaml.cs shown here:

```
namespace EngineeringLabUi.CustomControls
{
    [INotifyPropertyChanged]
    public partial class Rs422DeviceControlGroup : UserControl
    {
        public Rs422DeviceControlGroup()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region UseCheckedDp

        /// Gets or sets the the ischecked property on the use checkbox
        public bool UseChecked
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(UseCheckedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(UseCheckedProperty, value); }
        }

        public object UseCheckedDp { get; set; }

        /// Use checkbox dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UseCheckedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UseCheckedDp", typeof(bool),
                typeof(Rs422DeviceControlGroup), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        #endregion UseCheckedDp

        #region ReadTypeDp

        /// Gets or sets the the read type property on the use read type combo box
        public SerialOpEnumType? ReadType
        {
            get { return (SerialOpEnumType)GetValue(ReadTypedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ReadTypedProperty, value); }
        }

        public object ReadTypeDp { get; set; }

        /// Read type combo box dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ReadTypedProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ReadTypeDp", typeof(SerialOpEnumType),
                typeof(Rs422DeviceControlGroup), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        #endregion ReadTypeDp

        #region WriteTypeDp

        /// Gets or sets the the write type property on the use write type combo box
        public SerialOpEnumType? WriteType
        {
            get { return (SerialOpEnumType)GetValue(WriteTypeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(WriteTypeProperty, value); }
        }

        public object WriteTypeDp { get; set; }

        /// Write type combo box dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty WriteTypeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("WriteTypeDp", typeof(SerialOpEnumType),
                typeof(Rs422DeviceControlGroup), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        #endregion WriteTypeDp

        #region BaudRateDp

        /// Gets or sets the the baud rate  property on the baud rate combo box
        public SerialBaudRatesEnumType? BaudRate
        {
            get { return (SerialBaudRatesEnumType)GetValue(BaudRateProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BaudRateProperty, value); }
        }

        public object BaudRateDp { get; set; }

        /// Baud rate dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BaudRateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BaudRateDp", typeof(SerialBaudRatesEnumType),
                typeof(Rs422DeviceControlGroup), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        #endregion BaudRateDp

        #region ParityDp

        /// Gets or sets the the parity property on the parity combo box
        public Parity? Parity
        {
            get { return (Parity)GetValue(ParityProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ParityProperty, value); }
        }

        public object ParityDp { get; set; }

        /// Parity dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ParityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BaudRateDp", typeof(Parity),
                typeof(Rs422DeviceControlGroup), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        #endregion ParityDp

        #region DataBitsDp

        /// Gets or sets the the data bits property on the data bits combo box
        public SerialDataBitsEnumType? DataBits
        {
            get { return (SerialDataBitsEnumType)GetValue(DataBitsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataBitsProperty, value); }
        }

        public object DataBitsDp { get; set; }

        /// Data bits dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataBitsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DataBitsDp", typeof(SerialDataBitsEnumType),
                typeof(Rs422DeviceControlGroup), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        #endregion DataBitsDp

        #region StopBitsDp

        /// Gets or sets the the parity property on the stop bits combo box
        public StopBits? StopBits
        {
            get { return (StopBits)GetValue(StopBitsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StopBitsProperty, value); }
        }

        public object StopBitsDp { get; set; }

        /// Stop bits dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty StopBitsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StopBitsDp", typeof(StopBits),
                typeof(Rs422DeviceControlGroup), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        #endregion StopBitsDp

        #region FccPositionDp

        /// Gets or sets the the parity property on the stop bits combo box
        public FccPositionsEnumType? FccPosition
        {
            get { return (FccPositionsEnumType)GetValue(FccPositionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FccPositionProperty, value); }
        }

        public object FccPositionDp { get; set; }

        /// Stop bits dependency property
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FccPositionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("FccPositionDp", typeof(FccPositionsEnumType),
                typeof(Rs422DeviceControlGroup), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        #endregion FccPositionDp
    }
}
```

Then in my Rs422ConfigView.cs I have attempted to bind to these dependency properties:

```
  x:Class="EngineeringLabUi.Views.Rs422ConfigView"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:EngineeringLabUi.CustomControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EngineeringLabUi"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:EngineeringLabUi.ViewModels"
Title="RS422 Device Configuration"
Width="auto"
Height="auto"
MinWidth="100"
MinHeight="600"
MaxWidth="1300"
MaxHeight="700"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModels:Rs422ConfigViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="Rs422DeviceDataTemplate">
        <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Orientation="Vertical">
        <WrapPanel>
            <!--#region Rs422Dev0CtrlGrp-->
            <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup
                x:Name="Rs422Dev0CtrlGrp"
                BaudRateDp="{Binding ModelBaudRate}"
                DataBitsDp="{Binding ModelDataBits}"
                DataContext="{Binding Rs422DeviceColl[0], Mode=OneWay}"
                FccPositionDp="{Binding ModelFccPosition}"
                ParityDp="{Binding ModelParity}"
                ReadTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelReadType}"
                StopBitsDp="{Binding ModelStopBits}"
                UseCheckedDp="{Binding ViewModelUseChecked}"
                WriteTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelWriteType}" />
            <!--#endregion Rs422Dev0CtrlGrp-->
            <!--#region Rs422Dev1CtrlGrp-->
            <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup
                x:Name="Rs422Dev1CtrlGrp"
                BaudRateDp="{Binding ModelBaudRate}"
                DataBitsDp="{Binding ModelDataBits}"
                DataContext="{Binding Rs422DeviceColl[1], Mode=OneWay}"
                FccPositionDp="{Binding ModelFccPosition}"
                ParityDp="{Binding ModelParity}"
                ReadTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelReadType}"
                StopBitsDp="{Binding ModelStopBits}"
                UseCheckedDp="{Binding ViewModelUseChecked}"
                WriteTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelWriteType}" />
            <!--#endregion Rs422Dev1CtrlGrp-->
            <!--#region Rs422Dev2CtrlGrp-->
            <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup
                x:Name="Rs422Dev2CtrlGrp"
                BaudRateDp="{Binding ModelBaudRate}"
                DataBitsDp="{Binding ModelDataBits}"
                DataContext="{Binding Rs422DeviceColl[2], Mode=OneWay}"
                FccPositionDp="{Binding ModelFccPosition}"
                ParityDp="{Binding ModelParity}"
                ReadTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelReadType}"
                StopBitsDp="{Binding ModelStopBits}"
                UseCheckedDp="{Binding ViewModelUseChecked}"
                WriteTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelWriteType}" />
            <!--#endregion Rs422Dev2CtrlGrp-->
            <!--#region Rs422Dev3CtrlGrp-->
            <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup
                x:Name="Rs422Dev3CtrlGrp"
                BaudRateDp="{Binding ModelBaudRate}"
                DataBitsDp="{Binding ModelDataBits}"
                DataContext="{Binding Rs422DeviceColl[3], Mode=OneWay}"
                FccPositionDp="{Binding ModelFccPosition}"
                ParityDp="{Binding ModelParity}"
                ReadTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelReadType}"
                StopBitsDp="{Binding ModelStopBits}"
                UseCheckedDp="{Binding ViewModelUseChecked}"
                WriteTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelWriteType}" />
            <!--#endregion Rs422Dev3CtrlGrp-->
            <!--#region Rs422Dev4CtrlGrp-->
            <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup
                x:Name="Rs422Dev4CtrlGrp"
                BaudRateDp="{Binding ModelBaudRate}"
                DataBitsDp="{Binding ModelDataBits}"
                DataContext="{Binding Rs422DeviceColl[4], Mode=OneWay}"
                FccPositionDp="{Binding ModelFccPosition}"
                ParityDp="{Binding ModelParity}"
                ReadTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelReadType}"
                StopBitsDp="{Binding ModelStopBits}"
                UseCheckedDp="{Binding ViewModelUseChecked}"
                WriteTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelWriteType}" />
            <!--#endregion Rs422Dev4CtrlGrp-->
            <!--#region Rs422Dev5CtrlGrp-->
            <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup
                x:Name="Rs422Dev5CtrlGrp"
                BaudRateDp="{Binding ModelBaudRate}"
                DataBitsDp="{Binding ModelDataBits}"
                DataContext="{Binding Rs422DeviceColl[5], Mode=OneWay}"
                FccPositionDp="{Binding ModelFccPosition}"
                ParityDp="{Binding ModelParity}"
                ReadTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelReadType}"
                StopBitsDp="{Binding ModelStopBits}"
                UseCheckedDp="{Binding ViewModelUseChecked}"
                WriteTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelWriteType}" />
            <!--#endregion Rs422Dev5CtrlGrp-->
            <!--#region Rs422Dev6CtrlGrp-->
            <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup
                x:Name="Rs422Dev6CtrlGrp"
                BaudRateDp="{Binding ModelBaudRate}"
                DataBitsDp="{Binding ModelDataBits}"
                DataContext="{Binding Rs422DeviceColl[6], Mode=OneWay}"
                FccPositionDp="{Binding ModelFccPosition}"
                ParityDp="{Binding ModelParity}"
                ReadTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelReadType}"
                StopBitsDp="{Binding ModelStopBits}"
                UseCheckedDp="{Binding ViewModelUseChecked}"
                WriteTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelWriteType}" />
            <!--#endregion Rs422Dev6CtrlGrp-->
            <!--#region Rs422Dev7CtrlGrp-->
            <customControls:Rs422DeviceControlGroup
                x:Name="Rs422Dev7CtrlGrp"
                BaudRateDp="{Binding ModelBaudRate}"
                DataBitsDp="{Binding ModelDataBits}"
                DataContext="{Binding Rs422DeviceColl[7], Mode=OneWay}"
                FccPositionDp="{Binding ModelFccPosition}"
                ParityDp="{Binding ModelParity}"
                ReadTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelReadType}"
                StopBitsDp="{Binding ModelStopBits}"
                UseCheckedDp="{Binding ViewModelUseChecked}"
                WriteTypeDp="{Binding ViewModelWriteType}" />
            <!--#endregion Rs422Dev7CtrlGrp-->
        </WrapPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The Rs422DeviceColl[7] object referenced in the above code is inside my Rs422ConfigModel.cs:

```
        public Rs422ConfigModel()
    {

    }

    /* Ok so here is a problem...After changing the User class to be called UserModel I can see that the below observable collection for Users are
     * objects of the UseModel class.  In my observable collection I had used the AddUserControl which is the WPF control but instead I should be using the
     * UserControlModel instead which is a C# object
     */
    private static ObservableCollection<Rs422ConfigModel> _rs422ConfigModel = new ObservableCollection<Rs422ConfigModel>();

    public static ObservableCollection<Rs422ConfigModel> GetAddRs422Ctrl()
    {
        return _rs422ConfigModel;
    }

    // an object comes into this function from the AddUserViewModel:AddUserCtrlMethod
    public static void AddRs422Ctrl(Rs422ConfigModel ctrl)
    {
        // This is where it is actually added to the collection
        _rs422ConfigModel.Add(ctrl);
    }

    public bool? ModelUseChecked { get; set; }
    public SerialOpEnumType? ModelReadType { get; set; }
    public SerialOpEnumType? ModelWriteType { get; set; }
    public SerialBaudRatesEnumType? ModelBaudRate { get; set; }
    public Parity? ModelParity { get; set; }
    public SerialDataBitsEnumType? ModelDataBits { get; set; }
    public StopBits? ModelStopBits { get; set; }
    public FccPositionsEnumType? ModelFcccPosition { get; set; }
    public SerialDeviceStateEnumType? ModelState { get; set; }
}
```

I am confused about when and where to set DataContext for UserControls.  I have read that I should never set them directly inside the UserControl but all of these UserControls will only ever need the DataContext of the Rs422ConfigViewModel.  Also, I am not sure if each UserControl should have its own Rs422ConfigViewModel or not.  I'm not quite sure that is a good question either.

I have tried a simple project with just two windows and still can't figure it out.  I have signed up for a Udemy course to spin up faster but I did not find that too helpful either.  I hope someone can point out the missing link and I hope that this post helps others who have experience in C# but not MVVM.

List of some of the resources I have already researched:

- [A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435781/a-binding-can-only-be-set-on-a-dependencyproperty-of-a-dependencyobject)
- https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html
- [Using multiple instances of same user control simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230067/using-multiple-instances-of-same-user-control-simultaneously)
- https://medium.com/@mpcodes/wpf-c-mvvm-sample-application-14ffe10b5bf2
- [Data Binding on a UserControl - WPF, MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76714320/data-binding-on-a-usercontrol-wpf-mvvm)
- [WPF - MVVM binding in UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182133/wpf-mvvm-binding-in-usercontrol)
- [WPF - MVVM - UserControl binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55219357/wpf-mvvm-usercontrol-binding)
- [WPF - Content of two user controls bound to same instance of control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572249/wpf-content-of-two-user-controls-bound-to-same-instance-of-control)
- [Binding to UserControl DependencyProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985382/binding-to-usercontrol-dependencyproperty)
- [UserControl Command Binding in WPF using MVVM pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177602/usercontrol-command-binding-in-wpf-using-mvvm-pattern)
  -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402100/wpf-mvvm-binding-properties-on-usercontrols-to-viewmodel-of-container

Comment: "*I am confused about when and where to set DataContext for UserControls.*" - you would never explicitly set the DataContext of a UserControl anywhere. A UserControl - as any other control - is supposed to inherit the value of the DataContext property from its parent element, which is usually some kind of ContentPresenter or ContentControl, which in turn inherits the DataContext from its parent element. The only place where you explicitly set a DataContext is at the root of the visual tree, i.e. in a Window or a Page.

Comment: Besides that, it is unclear what exactly isn't working. Take a look at the Output Window in Visual Studio for possible data binding error messages when you debug the application.

Comment: A UserControl does also not need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged, because its dependency properties already provide their own notification mechanism.

Comment: And instead of eight explicitly declared controls in a WrapPanel you may want to use an ItemsControl that uses a WrapPanel as its ItemsPanel. The UserControl would be declared in the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl and thus automatically bind to the appropriate item of the ItemsSource collection. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: I would suggest to use external support for MVVM in WPF such as Prism which will reduce some complexities.